# Transitive reductions of transitive closure

Tags: dag, transitivity

Is there a name for the relationship between two DAGs `A,B` where `B` is *one of the* transitive reductions of the transitive closure `C` of `A`?

For example the connectivity of nodes in both graphs would still be the same.

For example, we can connect all nodes in `A` to their minimal elements (smallest subsets) in `A` and remove all other edges, leading to `B`.

Comment: Some authors require transitive reductions to be a subgraph of the original graph (an edge in the reduction must be an edge in the original graph), and some don't - a transitive reduction just has to be a graph on the same vertex set whose transitive closure is the same.

Comment: That is also what came to my mind but then I read the Wikipedia article of transitive reduction, where it says "The transitive reduction of a finite directed acyclic graph (a directed graph without directed cycles) is unique and is a subgraph of the given graph." Note that in my concept there might be edges in `B` that are not in the original graph `A`.

Comment: I was meaning that there seem to be two different notions kicking around which are in use, so perhaps just say "_a_ transitive closure of `A`" rather than "_the_ transitive closure of `A`", and the first time you introduce the concept make sure it's clear which notion you mean

Comment: @Joppy, I think your point is worth an answer, in particular if you could find one example for each view ("some authors do, some don't").